# All output on talend open studio is not inserting in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, talend

As Diagram and console shows the output of given job is--

1. Total Records
2. Current Job name
3. File property table
   here's file property table is inserted in database but Total Records and Current Job name is not inserting.

so how I can log remaining console output to MongoDB

I'm attaching Images of my output
[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your job design would be like this :

```
tFileInputExcel -> tFileOutputJson -> tFileProperties -> tHashOutput 
| 
OnSubjobOk
|
tFixedFlowInput -> main -> tSetGlobalVar (you will stock the Total Records and the Current Job name)
|
OnSubjobOk
|
tHashInput -> main ->tMap (call your 2 global Variables )->  tMongoDBOutput
```

NB :

- tHashInput  and tHashOutput  must have the same Schema don't forget That
- in tFixedFlowInput you have to create 2 variables (one for the total rows and one for the job Name  then in the `value` put same variables you are printing in tJava in your old job )

Here is how to add  **tHashInput and tHashOutput** components

https://help.talend.com/r/en-US/7.3/technical/where-can-i-find-thashinput-thashoutput-components

Comment: Ben but in your job there is no tjava component so how can I log Total Records and Job Name???

Comment: you can add it when ever you want

Comment: as you said it is simply a log

Comment: Ben I have also posted the answer with some errors. have a look please!!